# Plotting points on circle's circumference but coming up as a ellipse

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, geometry, scatter-plot

I have made a code (in python) that makes a point on the circumference of a circle at every 10 degrees:

```
rad = 75
originX = originY = 0
tenDegreePts = [[],[]]

for theta in range(0, 360, 10):
    b = (np.cos(theta))*rad
    a = (np.sin(theta))*rad
    tenDegreePts[0].append(originX+b)
    tenDegreePts[1].append(originY+a)

plt.plot(tenDegreePts[0],tenDegreePts[1],'o')
plt.ylim(-100,100)
plt.xlim(-100,100)
```

The program runs perfectly, but for some reason the circle has more of an elliptical shape. Also, the points on the graph aren't equal distances apart:

Scatter plot of points on  the circumference of a circle at every 10 degrees:
[image: scatter plot of the points on the circle]

(In the picture you can't see the axis but they go from -100 to 100 on both x and y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `plt.axis('equal')` to maintain the correct aspect ratio of the plot.

About the problem of the points not being evenly spaced: you give `theta` in degrees, but the trigonomial functions expect their inputs in radians. You can convert degrees to radians multiplying by 180 and dividing by Pi, as in the code.

I also rewrote the code a bit to make better use of [numpy's broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) tricks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

originX = originY = 0
theta = np.linspace(0, 360, 37)

for rad in range(15, 85, 10):
    tenDegreePtsX = np.cos(theta*np.pi/180) * rad + originX
    tenDegreePtsY = np.sin(theta*np.pi/180) * rad + originY
    plt.plot(tenDegreePtsX, tenDegreePtsY, 'o', ms=rad/10)

plt.ylim(-100,100)
plt.xlim(-100,100)
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image: corrected plot]

Answer (score 2):

Check https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html Which shows exactly this.

Copying it here for the people who are not familiar with how to read the docs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Plot circle of radius 3.

an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0, 0].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[0, 0].set_title('not equal, looks like ellipse', fontsize=10)

axs[0, 1].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[0, 1].axis('equal')
axs[0, 1].set_title('equal, looks like circle', fontsize=10)

axs[1, 0].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[1, 0].axis('equal')
axs[1, 0].set(xlim=(-3, 3), ylim=(-3, 3))
axs[1, 0].set_title('still a circle, even after changing limits', fontsize=10)

axs[1, 1].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[1, 1].set_aspect('equal', 'box')
axs[1, 1].set_title('still a circle, auto-adjusted data limits', fontsize=10)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]